# Python, ImageMagick and `subprocess`

Tags: python, parameters, imagemagick, glob

I'm trying to assemble images with a call to ImageMagick's `montage` from a Python script like this:

```
 command = "montage"
 args = "-tile {}x{} -geometry +0+0 \"*.png\" out.png".format( width, height)
 sys.stdout.write( "  {} {}\n".format(command, args) )
 print subprocess.call( [command, args] )
```

However, montage only shows usage. If I run the command manually, everything works. ImageMagick is supposed to support filename globbing in Windows, so *.png is expanded.
But apparently, this behaviour is suppressed by `subprocess`.
Do I have to use `glob` to feed `montage` with a list of the filenames?

**Further information**
Thanks so far. But even when I use:

```
command = "montage"
tile = "-tile {}x{}".format( width, height)
geometry = "-geometry +0+0"
infile = "*.png"
outfile = "out.png"
sys.stdout.write( "  {} {} {} {} {}\n".format(command, tile, geometry, infile, outfile) )
print [command, tile, geometry, infile, outfile]
#~ print subprocess.call( [command, tile, geometry, infile, outfile] )
print subprocess.call( ['montage', '-tile 9x6', '-geometry +0+0', '*.png', 'out.png'] )
```

I get an error:

```
 Magick: unrecognized option `-tile 9x6' @ error/montage.c/MontageImageCommand/1631.
```

I'm on Windows 7, ImageMagick 6.6.5-7 2010-11-05 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org, Python 2.7

Comment: Problem persists with ImageMagick-6.6.7-7-Q16-windows-dll.exe.

Comment: Notice the backtick in the error message \`<option>'? No, that seems ok:
     F:\xx>montage -nonsense in.png out.png
 
     Magick: unrecognized option `-nonsense' @ error/montage.c/MontageImageCommand/1227.

Comment: '-tile' and 'widthxheight' must be two different list items. The same goes for everything on the command line that is separated by a space. The only spaces that should be present within list items are the ones that you would escape if you were to run the command directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `[command, args]`, you should pass `['montage', '-tile', '{}x{}'.format(...), '-geometry'...]` as first argument. You might need `shell=True` as well.

Comment: Before anyone else misses it: Note that even the arguments ({}x{}) to the options (-tile) are seperate list elements!

Comment: Update: `shell=True` fixed it on Windows 7 but OS X (10.6) needed it without.

Comment: I don't know why but in OSX(10.11) works only without shell=True.

Answer (score 3):

jd already gave you the solution, but you didn't read it carefully ;)

This is incorrect:

```
subprocess.call( ['montage', '-tile 9x6', '-geometry +0+0', '*.png', 'out.png'] )
```

This is correct:

```
subprocess.call( ['montage', '-tile', '9x6', '-geometry', '+0+0', '*.png', 'out.png'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call` expects the entire command to be split into a list (with each argument as a separate element of the list). Try:

```
import shlex
command = "montage"
args = "-tile {}x{} -geometry +0+0 \"*.png\" out.png".format( width, height)
subprocess.call( shlex.split('{} {}'.format(command, args)) )
```